# SQLServer Container looses Data when stopped although it is mounted to volume

Tags: docker, docker-volume

please bear in mind this is my first time posting here I might not know all the rules and stuff.

so I have just started working with dockers and images. I created a small .Net app and I used MsSQLServer docker image in my app. The app gets connected with the server and I am able to create database using CodeFirst approach (add-migration and update database works fine).

i am running my SQL container with -rm mode. Although it has a volume mounted to it but i have to create database every time i rerun the container.
I read that if we want our data not to get lost when we delete the container we have to mount volumes to our container. i had done the same thing using MongoDb docker image and it worked fine. my data is still present even when i stop and rerun my MongoContainer. but my MSSQL is unable to retain data.
here is the command i m using to run my docker image ( i know about docker-compose but i am avoiding using it for now)

```
docker run -d --rm --name mssqlserver -p 1433:1433 -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=********** -v sqlData:/data/db  mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
```

Note: this says it will not delete named volume with --rm
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up---rm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you mount the volume on is a Linux path, so you need to use forward slashes rather than back-slashes, like this

```
docker run -d --rm --name mssqlserver -p 1433:1433 -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=********** -v sqlData:/var/opt/mssql mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
```

Comment: sorry, this is the initial run command.  i have edited it.

Comment: MSSQL stores the data under `/var/opt/mssql`, so that's the path you need to map a volume to. Each database stores it's data in different places and `/data/db` is where Mongo stores the database. Mssql stores it in a different place.

Comment: thank you so much. this fixed my problem. 
how can i mark this comment as answer?

Comment: Glad it helped. I think there's a checkmark on the left side of the question you can click to mark the answer as accepted.